# Confusion about systems involving integrals

Tags: continuous-signals, system-identification

$$y_1(t)=\int_a^tx(τ)dτ$$
$$y_2(t)=\int_a^bx(t)dt$$

I'm confused about what are the input signals in each of these systems.

To my understanding, in the second case the input signal is $x$ since both $y$ and $x$ are functions of $t$.

However in the first case we see that $t$ is an upper limit of an integral, so I thought that in fact the input signal is not $x$ but $X(t) =\int_a^tx(τ)dτ$. That would make $y_1$ an identity system as $y_1(t) = X(t)$. That doesn't seem correct. Is this a notational problem or is my logic flawed?

Comment: $y_1(t)$ is a function of time that will vary whenever the input $x(t)$ is non-zero (and $\tau$ is a dummy variable of the definite integral).  $y_2(t)$ is a function of time but is guaranteed to be a constant function of time equal to the integral on the right (and $t$, on the right-hand side, is a dummy variable of the integral).

Comment: That would make $y_1$ a function of two variables since you are setting both the integrand and the upper limit of integration. Am I wrong?

Comment: yes, yer wrong.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: do you understand that the variable of integration is a dummy variable?

Comment: Yes, but the integrand (the function to be integrated) is not a dummy variable. The integrand is the input signal, ie an input to the function $y_1$ (system). But so is the upper limit of integration. Mathematically speaking...

Comment: Okay. I now realize that the output is not a value but a function. I think my confusion arised from interpreting systems as regular functions of t.